# Set of points where sequence of measurable functions is bounded from below and unbounded from above

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

We are given a space X with $\sigma$-algebra (of subsets of X) $\mathbb{F}$ and a sequence of measurable (w.r.t  $\mathbb{F}$) functions $f_n: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
Now consider a set $$H = \{x \in X :  \text{the sequence}  \{f_n(x)\}^\infty_{n=1} \text{is unbounded from above and bounded from below}  \}$$ .
We want to show that $H \in \mathbb{F}$.

---

**My attempt or rather intuition:**
$H$ can be written as intersection of
 $$A = \{x\in X: \text{the sequence is bounded from below}  \}$$

and $X-B$, where $$B = \{x\in X: \text{the sequence is bounded from above} \}$$
Now since $A$ and $X-B$ are "sort of"* inverse images of $[m,\infty]$ and $[-\infty,M]$ respectively ($m$ is the lower bound and $M$ is the upper bound) of functions $f_n$ which are measurable then H is "constructed" from sets that are in $\mathbb{F}$ using "legal" set operations that keep them inside $\mathbb{F}$.
* I wrote *sort of* because they are rather countable unions or intersections of inverse images (?)

Is this intuition correct? Could you add precision to this reasoning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your idea of writing $H = A \cup (X-B)$, one can proceed as follows: to show that $A$ is measurable, write
$$ A = \bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \{ x: f_n(x) \geq -k \text{  for all  } n \in \mathbb{N} \} = \bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{N} } \bigcap_{ n \in \mathbb{N}} \{x: f_n(x) \geq -k \}.$$
Since each function $f_n$ is measurable, each set $\{x: f_n(x) \geq -k \}$ is measurable.  Taking the intersection over $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and the union over $k \in \mathbb{N}$ preserves measurability.  A similar argument shows that your set $B$ is measurable.

Answer (score 1):

A different approach: Both $\limsup f_n, \liminf f_n$ are measurable functions from $X$ into $[-\infty,\infty].$ The set of interest equals

$$\{x\in X: \limsup f_n (x) = \infty\}\cap \{x\in X: \liminf f_n (x) > -\infty\},$$

which is a measurable set.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's way simpler...